# Move row data to columns (not transpose)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have `user - child` relationship as multiple rows

```
   user_id  child_id  birth_date gender
0        1       1.0  2018-01-01      m
1        1       2.0  2018-01-03      f
2        1       3.0  2018-01-04      m
3        2       NaN        None   None
```

Now I want to pick youngest and eldest kid and put them in columns

```
   user_id kid_1_birth_date kid_1_gender kid_2_birth_date kid_2_gender
0        1       2018-01-01            m       2018-01-04            m
1        2             None         None             None         None
```

I'm currently doing `groupby` and followed by `group.iterrows` and add rows to newly created dataframe, wonder if there's better way

I'm using the dataframe and converting to tf.data using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` , and I'm inputting youngest kid and eldest kid's age/gender , that's why I'm converting the data in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way from `drop_duplicates`, then `merge`

```
df1=df.sort_values('birth_date').drop_duplicates('user_id')
df2=df.sort_values('birth_date').drop_duplicates('user_id',keep='last')
df1.drop('child_id',1).merge(df2.drop('child_id',1),on='user_id',suffixes=('young','old'))
Out[474]: 
   user_id birth_dateyoung genderyoung birth_dateold genderold
0        1      2018-01-01           m    2018-01-04         m
1        2             NaT        None           NaT      None
```

Comment: aye,, panda must be a playful animal.. thanks~, curious how do you copy the data (without comma) and use it to generate an answer..

Comment: @eugene guess you are talking about [pd.read_clipboard()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html)